# Loading data from Firebase with React

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a firebase location with [a list of patients](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QnAQ2.png)

I am trying to reference this location and save it in the state of my react component to later pass to a drop down. I am pretty new to REACT, so i am not sure if this is this best way to this.

```
import * as firebase from "firebase";

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      patient: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    let patientList = "";
    var rootRef = firebase
      .database()
      .ref()
      .child("patient");
    rootRef.on("child_added", snap => {
      this.setState({
        patient: snap.val().label
      });
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <li>{this.state.patient}</li>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

However this code is returning only the last label in the firebase location. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one

```
rootRef.on("child_added", snap => {

    // Store all the labels in array
    var patients = [];
    snapshot.forEach(function(snap){
        var row = snap.val();
        patients.push(row.label);
    });

    // Store label array into state
    this.setState({
        patient: patients
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help your case to implement the real time patient list.

```
rootRef.on("child_added", snap => {

    var patients = this.state.patient || [];
    snapshot.forEach(snap => {
        var row = snap.val();
        patients.push(row.label);
    });

    this.setState({
        patient: patients
    });
```

I hope it helps. Thanks!!